# Overriding methods in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, overriding

Sometimes I accidentally forget to call the superclass's method in C++ when I override a method.

Is there any way to help figure out when I'm overriding a method with, so that I don't forget to call the superclass's method? (Something like Java's `@Override`, except that C++ doesn't have annotations...)

Comment: C++11 has an `override` member function decorator, but it's not required so I don't think it will help in your case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force execution of parent's method before child's method without explicit call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344395/force-execution-of-parents-method-before-childs-method-without-explicit-call)

Comment: Why would you want to call the method inherited from the parent class evrytime you override a method? What would you do if the method was abstract in the parent class? I would suggest using a nonvirtual public method in the base class which calls a protected virtual method instead, which will likely solve the same problem.

Comment: The unobvious need to call the superclass method is often a code smell. Try to remove the need from the design first, e.g. by making reducing the number of classes that act both as interfaces and as implementations.

Comment: @thiton: I'm looking for something more like a warning, not an implicit call on my behalf.

Comment: @Grizzly : The nonvirtual public method should call a _private_ virtual method, otherwise it's still possible for the derived class to call the base class' implementation. I.e., making the virtual method private makes it clear that the base class' implementation should _not_ be called by derived classes.

Comment: For one thing @Override in Java doesn't exist to remind you to call super class's method, it ensures that you are actually overriding a super class method. Anyway, this question is about C++, like others have said override doesn't necessarily have to result in base class member being called, in some cases it can be incorrect.

Comment: @ildjarn: Why shouldn't it be possible for the derived class to call it? It should just generally be unnecesary, but if the derived class has a reason to call the base method, why not.

Comment: @Grizzly : It sounded like you were advocating the approach in FredLarson's answer wherein the virtual member function is pure; in that scenario the base class has no implementation to call, so it's a matter of clarity for the derived class' authors. If I misunderstood then my apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One suggestion is the [Non-Virtual Inferface Idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm). I.e., make your public methods non-virtual and have them call private or protected virtual methods that derived classes can override to implement their specific behavior.

If you don't have control over the base class, you could perhaps use an intermediate class:

```
class Foo // Don't control this one
{
  public:
    virtual void action();
};

class Bar : public Foo // Intermediate base class
{
  public:
    virtual void action()
    {
       doAction();
       Foo::action();
    }

  protected:
    virtual void doAction() = 0;
};
```

Derive your classes from `Bar` and override `doAction()` on each. You could even have `doBeforeAction()` and `doAfterAction()` if necessary.

Comment: What if I don't have control over the base class, though?

Comment: @Mehrdad: That definitely makes it tougher. You could maybe make an intermediate base class to help out.

Comment: Also known as [the template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: @ildjarn: Yeah, see the article I linked. Herb says this is a restricted form of template method that deserves its own name. Whatever works.

Comment: Oh I see... yeah it definitely works for smaller interfaces but doesn't scale well to bigger stuff. +1 though, seems like the best solution so far.

Comment: @Mehrdad : On the contrary, it's hard to maintain a clean design with a large code base _without_ using patterns like this.

Answer (score 3):

With regards to Java's `@Override`, there is a direct equivalent in C++11, namely the [`override` special identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Explicit_overrides_and_final).

Sadly, neither `@Override` nor `override` solve the problem since: (a) they're optional; (b) the responsibility of calling the base class's method still rests with the programmer.

Furthermore, I don't know of any widely available method that would address the problem (it's quite tricky, esp. given that you don't *necessarily* want to call the base class's method -- how is the machine to know?).

Comment: +1 nice explanation, even though it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Í'm not aware of a common mechanism to do this.

In C++ if you're needing to use the base class's functionality in addition to added child functionality you should look at the template method pattern. This way the common logic always lives in the base class and there's no way to forget to execute it, and you override in the child only the piece you need to change.